Instruction references an unknown account QPg9yiJ4vqchkgBjJuhDtQRpHQcC1dDAXVafUyVA32H
I have this,
    let bond_purchase_ix: spl_token::solana_program::instruction::Instruction = (PurchaseBondV2 {
        kyc_account: find_kyc_pda(user.key()).0,
        user_wallet: user.key(),
        bond_account,
        issuance_account,
        mint_account: bond.mint,
        payment_account,
        payment_token_account: get_associated_token_address(
            &payment_account,
            &payment_feed.payment_mint
        ),
        user_token_account: get_associated_token_address_with_program_id(
            &user.key(),
            &bond.mint,
            &spl_token_2022::id()
        ),
        user_payment_token_account: get_associated_token_address(
            &user.key(),
            &payment_feed.payment_mint
        ),
        payment_mint_account: payment_feed.payment_mint,
        payment_feed_account,
        payment_base_price_feed_account: payment_feed.base_price_feed,
        payment_quote_price_feed_account,
        token2022_program: spl_token_2022::id(),
        associated_token_program: spl_associated_token_account::id(),
        token_program: spl_token::id(),
        system_program: system_program::id(),
    }).instruction_with_remaining_accounts(ix_args, &remaining_accounts);

its meant to provide the instruction which i will pass to an invoked_signed.
Yes, the instruction and struct PurchaseBondV2, is coming from another Solana program..
the issue is i'am getting an error An account required by the instruction is missing
so my question, what i exactly am i supposed to pass to the invoked_signed account_info
    invoke_signed(
        &bond_purchase_ix,
        &[
           // &account_infos,
        ],
        &[&[b"program_authority", &[ctx.bumps.program_authority]]]

the values passed into PurchaseBondV2 struct, is not gotten from me, they are all derived from the other solana program.
i.e they are already functions to derive the values passed
e.g find_kyc_pda(user.key()) and the address it returns is a valid address
but the solana program is telling me that that particular account is missing in the instruction

33: "Instruction references an unknown account QPg9yiJ4vqchkgBjJuhDtQRpHQcC1dDAXVafUyVA32H"
34: "Program GWKa83spWx4csTShf39WeDNKw4orzK5shMn7PzDofpfd consumed 252982 of 599700 compute units"
35: "Program GWKa83spWx4csTShf39WeDNKw4orzK5shMn7PzDofpfd failed: An account required by the instruction is missing"


the particular account is valid only that its not coming from my program.
what might be the issue?

On the Solana blockchain, it's impossible to fetch accounts dynamically, so if you want to CPI into another program, you must provide that program and all of the accounts required for the program to process the instruction. Since you have user.key(), I'm assuming that user is one of the account infos that you need. On top of that, you'll need account infos for spl_token::id(), system_program::id(), bond.mint, etc etc etc
